# How do I map java.util.Date to sys.datetime

Tags: java, sql-server, datetime, jdbc, jasper-reports

I am upgrading our [JDBC](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/) driver to mssql-jdbc-6.2.1 so we can move to SQL server 2016. Everything works fine with the new driver except our reports. We have 6000+ reports that use `java.util.Date`. With the previous driver these were treated as `DATETIME` in SQL but the new driver treats them as `DATE`.  The reports are failing on code like "DATEADD(MINUTE, ..." since this is not supported with DATE.

I tried

```
java.util.Map map = conn.getTypeMap();
map.put("sys.datetime", java.util.Date.class);
conn.setTypeMap(map);
```

But apparently `setTypeMap` is not implemented in the MS driver.

Rewriting all the reports is not an option. Is there anyway to override this mapping?

Comment: are you using plain jdbc or some ORM over it?

Comment: Plain JDBC.  We hand the connection to a JasperFillManager.fillReport

Comment: It's not clear to me how the JDBC driver "interprets" a `java.util.Date` as a particular SQL type. Certainly the driver can map a SQL Server type to a JDBC type (e.g., `DATETIME` -> `java.sql.Timestamp`), but I'm not sure how that would necessarily work in the opposite direction. Would this be a function of the Jasper Reports software? If so, then consider adding that tag to the question.

Comment: It may be Jasper related. Since the problem started with changing the driver, I suspected it. However I was unable to reproduce the error in a test app outside of Jasper.  We are using Jasper version 3.7.0, but I tried 6.4.1 and received the same error.

Comment: It is a Jasper Reports issue. JRJdbcQueryExecuter.setStatementParameter converts java.util.Date to java.sql.Date.  We were able to get away with this before since our old driver treated java.sql.Date as a DATEIME.